# Finding value using Xpath (with no unique identifiers) in Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, try-catch, findelement

I'm having trouble trying to get the colour of a vehicle in Selenium using Python. I've checked YouTube, stackoverflow and all the usual resources but can't seem to find an answer that makes sense (I'm relatively new to Python and Selenium). I'm currently undertaking a project to automate the fetching of vehicle colour from the gov.uk website into an excel sheet based on the Vehicle Registration number already present on the spreadsheet. The code isn't finished yet, as I want to get over this Xpath hurdle first!

I need to fetch the 'Blue' value from this code:

```html
<dl class="summary-no-action">
<div class="govuk-summary-list__row">
<dt>Registration number</dt>
<dd>
<div class="reg-mark-sm">WJ06 HYF</div>
</dd>
</div>
<div class="govuk-summary-list__row">
<dt>Make</dt>
<dd>VOLKSWAGEN</dd>
</div>
<div class="govuk-summary-list__row">
<dt>Colour</dt>
<dd>BLUE</dd>
</div>
</dl>
```

However, as you can see, they have made it very difficult as there is no specific ID, class, tag name, etc to work with so I'm assuming Xpath is my only option? could anyone help me as to the best implementation of this? My assumption is to find the first 'dd' tag underneath 'Colour' but I don't know how to write this!
Here is the code snippet I'm working on that I have so far:

```
try:
main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "summary-no-action"))
    )

div = main.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Colour")
for article in div:
    header = article.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "dd")
    print(header.text)
finally:
driver.quit()
```

I'm aware the line 'div = main.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Colour")' is incorrect, but I need to replace it with something so that I may fetch the colour present in the 'dd' tag underneath.

This is what I had originally, but it brings back all the values in the "summary-no-action" class name:

```
try:
main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "summary-no-action"))
    )

div = main.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "govuk-summary-list__row")
for article in div:
    header = article.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "dd")
    print(header.text)
finally:
driver.quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

For reference, here is the whole code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver =     
webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

driver.get ("https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/")

time.sleep(5)

search = driver.find_element(By.ID ,                 
"wizard_vehicle_enquiry_capture_vrn_vrn")
search.send_keys("wj06hyf")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "summary-no-action"))
    )

div = main.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "govuk-summary-list__row")
for article in div:
    header = article.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "dd")
    print(header.text)
finally:
driver.quit()
```

Comment: The website in question is https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` to get the value `BLUE`. first identify the `dt` tag with text `colour` and following `dd` tag

```
//dt[text()='Colour']/following::dd[1]
```

code:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//dt[text()='Colour']/following::dd[1]"))).text)
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the text ***Blue*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "dl.summary-no-action div:last-child dd"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//dl[@class='summary-no-action']//div[@class='govuk-summary-list__row']/dt[text()='Colour']//following-sibling::dd[1]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```